# Help identifying bike , Cinelli S. C

Tags: identify-this-bike

Need help identifying frame type says Cinelli S.C. made in Italy. Looks like a number of 1141 is blue light weight has campagnolo gears, shimano 600 front and back brakes, Nuevo Necorn & sprocket wellgo peddles possible # SACH5 LY94 and cinelli handle  bars 64'40
It's blue has  diamond shape at ever joint.

Comment: Provide photos. The famous Cinelli frame is the Super Corsa. Wouldn't it be nice if you had one of those.

Comment: Cinelli type 64 bars are also known as Giro D'Italia and were a popular choice historically because they are quite short and shallow.